# Pickling object instance gives TypeError: __new__() missing required positional arguments

Tags: python, sockets, pickle, subclassing

I am creating a board game in python that requires me to send objects created by a custom Hex() class that is a subclass of tuple. The problem I face is that when the server receives the pickled message (a tuple containing a string and the Hex object), it throws the following Error:

TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'r' and 's'

I'm relatively new to OOP but I believe that the server is attempting to create the Hex object when it unpacks the tuple message, however it obviously doesn't have the required information to recreate the original object as it is all packaged up in the object itself.

If anyone could suggest a way I can successfully send my Hex object from client to server and back that would be appreciated.

Code below:

```
server.py

import socket
import pickle

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 57343
SOCK = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SOCK.bind((HOST, PORT))
SOCK.listen()

print('Server active, waiting for connections...')


conn, addr = SOCK.accept()
print('Connected to:', addr)
conn.send(pickle.dumps('conn test'))
print('test message sent to', conn)

while True:
    try:
        print('waiting for data')
        data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(2048))
        command, info = data
        if command == 'move':
            print('Received message', data)
        elif command == 'get':
            pass
        conn.sendall(pickle.dumps('game'))
    except (EOFError, ConnectionResetError) as err:
        print(err)
        break
print('Lost connection')
conn.close()
```

```
client.py

import tmp_hex_lib as hl
from network import Network

def main():
    game_over = False
    moves = []
    attack_switch = False
    net = Network()
    net.get_player()
    while not game_over:  # main game loop
        try:
            net.send(('get', None))
        except:
            game_over = True
            print("Couldn't find game")
            break

        selected_hex = hl.Hex(-13, 10, 3)
        print('selected_hex has type:', type(selected_hex))

        moves.append(selected_hex)
        if attack_switch:
            net.send(('attack', None))
        else:
            net.send(('move', 'this message works'))
            net.send(('move', selected_hex))  # if any other type is sent, game runs fine
        attack_switch = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
network.py

import socket
import pickle

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "127.0.0.1"
        self.port = 57343
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.player = self.connect()

    def get_player(self):
        return self.player

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            print('connecting to server')
            data = pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
            print('Received data:', data)
            return data
        except EOFError as err:
            print(err)

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except socket.error as err:
            print(err)
```

```
tmp_hex_lib.py

class Hex(tuple):
    def __new__(self, q, r, s):
        return tuple.__new__(self, (q, r, s))

    def __init__(self, q, r, s):
        self.q = q
        self.r = r
        self.s = s
        assert not (round(q + r + s) != 0), "q + r + s must be 0"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after consulting the pickle documentation, I found a passage about pickling class instances. It seems that if you are defining your own `__new__()` method, you must also define a method `__getnewargs__(self)` that returns all the variables required by `__new__()` as a tuple. For instance (no pun intended) my case would be:

```
tmp_hex_lib.py

class Hex(tuple):
    def __new__(self, q, r, s):
        return tuple.__new__(self, (q, r, s))

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return self.q self.r, self.s

    def __init__(self, q, r, s):
        self.q = q
        self.r = r
        self.s = s
        assert not (round(q + r + s) != 0), "q + r + s must be 0"
```

Hope this helps others!

Comment: A note: You'll probably be better off defining `Hex` [using `typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple); right now, you've actually got two unrelated copies of each value, one (immutable) copy stored in the underlying `tuple` structure, and another (mutable) copy stored in the `__dict__` for `q`, `r` and `s`. `typing.NamedTuple` (or `collections.namedtuple`, which is slightly less configurable) will *only* store the immutable copy, and auto-generate `property`s that make that single copy available under the `q`, `r` and `s` names.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the advice, the full Hex class actually started out as `NamedTuple` that I found online, I converted it into a class as a) as a little practice project when I was starting out and b) because it seemed like a bit of a 'hacky' approach, I didn't realise there was an actual distinction between the two ways of writing it so thank for that, I probably will convert it back!